# How to group data vertically in rdlc reports

Tags: grouping, rdlc

i have data in following format:

```
AssetID  AssetName          AssetMaster      AssetMain          OpeningValue 
1        0100101 Generator  01 Electronic    01001 Equipments   150
2        0100102 Heater     01 Electronic    01001 Equipments   100
```

I want to show this data in rdlc report in this format:

```
Asset                      OpeningValue
01 Electronic
01001 Equipments    
0100101 Generator          150       
0100102 Heater             100
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make this using several groups. 
Group on:

1. AssetMaster
2. AssetMain
3. AssetName

Good luck